# DocuSign warning -there is a discrepancy between the payment items and the total but the total is correnct

Tags: docusignapi

DocuSign payment warning:
[image]

How to get rid of this warning?
You can see the total on the top is correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore this warning. The money should come in, as it's just a warning, not an error.

We're looking internally into the root cause, but we don't yet have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same warning. For me the solution was to use Number Tabs to hold the line item values. The warning went away when I made the "formula" equal to the sum of the number tabs multiplied by 100.

This is the PHP code I'm using.

```php
$formula_tabs = $tabs->getFormulaTabs() ?: [];
$number_tabs = $tabs->getNumberTabs() ?: [];

$number_tabs[] = new Number([
    'name' => 'FirstAmount',
    'tab_label' => 'FirstAmount',
    'value' => $amount_1,
    'conceal_value_on_document' => 'true',
    'document_id' => '1',
    'page_number' => '1'
]);

$number_tabs[] = new Number([
    'name' => 'SecondAmount',
    'tab_label' => 'SecondAmount',
    'value' => $amount_2,
    'conceal_value_on_document' => 'true',
    'document_id' => '1',
    'page_number' => '1'
]);

$line_item1 = new PaymentLineItem([
    'name' => 'item1',
    'description' => 'First Item',
    'amount_reference' => 'FirstAmount'
]);

$line_item2 = new PaymentLineItem([
    'name' => 'item2',
    'description' => 'Second Item',
    'amount_reference' => 'SecondAmount'
]);

$payment_details = new PaymentDetails([
    'gateway_account_id' => $gateway_id,
    'currency_code' => 'USD',
    'gateway_name' => 'stripe',
    'payment_option' => 'save_and_authorize',
    'line_items' => [$line_item1, $line_item2]
]);

$formula_tabs[] = new FormulaTab([
    'tab_label' => 'payment',
    'formula' => '([FirstAmount] + [SecondAmount]) * 100',  // convert amount to pennies
    'round_decimal_places' => 2,
    'payment_details' => $payment_details,
    'hidden' => true,
    'required' => true,
    'locked' => true,
    'document_id' => $did_str,
    'page_number' => '1',
    'x_position' => '0',
    'y_position' => '0'
]);

$tabs->setFormulaTabs($formula_tabs);
$tabs->setNumberTabs($number_tabs);
```